# How to Disable Window "Show" Animation?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dialog, window

Whenever a window is shown in Windows, it has a quick display animation that scales/fades it in. Is there anyway method to skip that animation and make it appear immediately? I've managed to do it a couple ways, but they all involve removing the WS_THICCFRAME that I want to maintain.

Is there an event I could cancel or override? Any functions I could use?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Let the user decide whether animations are enabled.

Comment: I think you want `const void* attrib = (const void*)TRUE; DwmSetWindowAttribute(m_hWnd, DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED, &attrib, sizeof(attrib));`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Worked flawlessly! Please make that an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DwmSetWindowAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmsetwindowattribute), with `DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED`, will disable window's animimation:

```
BOOL attrib = TRUE;
DwmSetWindowAttribute(m_hWnd, DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED, &attrib, sizeof(attrib));
```

Side note,

When animation is disabled, and you minimize/restore the window, the transition will look a little odd.

Personally I prefer to show some windows without animation, then restore default behavior after the window is shown (call `DwmSetWindowAttribute` again with `attrib = FALSE;`)